# Where can I ask for programming book recommendations?

Tags: discussion

As a *programmer*, I usually learn new skills by reading books. It seems like stackoverflow consider book recommendations questions as [not constructive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258839/best-git-book-for-a-noob). Where can I look for book recommendations, mainly programming related books?

Comment: Related: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/can-the-rules-on-book-advice-be-clarified-in-the-faq

Comment: What's a book??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book

Comment: @ohho personally, I just go for [all the books](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/) and then see what is useful and not.

Answer (score 2):

A few ways:

1. **Look at your local or an online bookseller.** Check out a Barnes & Noble or just your local library. If not, Amazon and Google are great tools for finding recommendation in reviews and such.
2. **Ask or look on forums.** Most forums about programming already have tons of threads containing book recommendations.
3. **IRC!** IRC is still alive and well. A lot of gurus hang out on their favorite languages respective IRC channels, and (if you know how to ask) they're almost always willing to help.

Comment: Forums, ok. Please suggest a forum which contains a better answer than this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258839/best-git-book-for-a-noob.

Comment: @ohho part of the problem there is that is Stack Overflow - neither Stack Overflow nor Programmers.SE are forums.  Your best bet would be to identify a forum on the subject (for example, for git https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/git-users ) and ask there.  That said, please check the FAQ if it exists and look to see if other book recommendations exist there to see if it would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to know if a book is good for me, I go on amazon.com and search for the book. Then, I read the review at the bottom. I often get all the informations I need about the book. Also, some review point me to other book that may suit my needs better. I start from this point and often end up having 10 to 15 tabs opens in Chrome with a lot of book to choose from.